# How to filtering column base condition SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following data:

[image]

I want to show it to be:

[image]

I only want to display a column whose maximum value is 1 in MYSQL. Thanks

Comment: It can be done using dynamic-SQL. Write a stored procedure and then use variables to store names of columns with maximum value 1. In last step, choose variable names as dynamic SQL query's select list.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

A query always returns a fixed number of columns. 
There is no way to write a query that retro-acts on its own definition.

The best you can do is get A + MAX(A) on each row (+ the same for every column), using window functions rather that aggregate functions.
If you are coding an application connected to this DB, it will help you determine your criteria at the very first record you read.

```
SELECT Name, A, MAX(A) OVER () AS MaxA, B, MAX(B) OVER () AS MaxB, C, MAX(C) OVER () AS MaxC, D, MAX(D) OVER () AS MaxD
FROM T
```